# JavaScript: SyntaxError missing ) after argument list

Tags: javascript, debugging

```
var quadraticFormula = function(a, b, c) {

        console.log((-b + sqrt( (b*b) - 4 * a * c)) / 2a) };

quadraticFormula(2,2,2)
```

I am a beginner trying to make a simple quadratic equation calculator on javascript. I keep on getting a syntax error message saying "missing ) after argument list". What is wrong with my code?

Comment: theres a semicolon missing after the `console.log(...)`

Comment: @Paul: that doesn't matter in JS. @Tae Rugh: `2a` isn't a valid token. *(I assume you have a `sqrt` function somewhere.)*

Answer (score 4):

Try adding a `*` sign in `2a`:

```
var quadraticFormula = function(a, b, c) {

        console.log((-b + Math.sqrt( (b*b) - 4 * a * c)) / (2*a));

};
```

Also `sqrt` is part of `Math` so invoke it with `Math.sqrt`. Notice that `quadraticFormula(2,2,2)` will print NaN as it will try to do the square root of a negative number: (2*2) - 4 * 2 * 2.

Edit:
I wrapped 2*a inside `()` to correct the quadratic formula.

Comment: They probably intend `(2 * a)` if that's what they were trying to do with `2a` but +1.