# javascript SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have code like below but i am getting syntax error in 'onkeyup' function..

```
$('#file_lists').append('<div class="custom_text"><input type="text" onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^1-9]/g,'');" name="custom_time" id="'+rands+'" value="1"></div>').after($("#final_result"));
```

please suggest me how to use this function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript: SyntaxError missing ) after argument list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31171211/javascript-syntaxerror-missing-after-argument-list)

Comment: `$('#file_lists').append('<div class="custom_text"><input type="text" onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^1-9]/g,\'\');" name="custom_time" id="' + rands + '" value="1"></div>').after($("#final_result"));
`

Comment: Note the difference: you have `''` in the middle of the string literal specified with single (`'`) quotes. The parser thinks the string ends there and another begins. You need to escape those characters like Rayon did: `\'`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Escape the single quotes in the `replace` function (`.replace(/[^1-9]/g,\'\')`) `''` => `\'\'`:

```
$('#file_lists')
 .append('<div class="custom_text"><input type="text" onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^1-9]/g,\'\');" name="custom_time" id="'+rands+'" value="1"></div>')
 .after($("#final_result"));
```